# Could a Tree grow around a humanoid being?

Tags: internal-consistency, flora

So, let’s say a group of survivors tie an immortal being to a young tree sapling. The immortal does not need food, nor water, so can survive indefinitely.

After about 100 years, could that young tree sapling grow around the immortal being, with its body still intact underneath a tree?

[image]

Basically, I Want something like this, or similar

Comment: Yes: https://www.thevintagenews.com/2016/08/29/the-real-story-behind-a-boy-left-his-bike-chained-to-a-tree-when-he-went-away-to-war-in-1914/. This phenomenon is only about 50 years old, not 100, but shows that the concept is sound.

Comment: @cobaltduck, that looked like the basis of an acceptable answer....

Comment: Fallout! I love those games :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but ...

[image]

[image]

It is one thing to get trees to grow round metal or stone but what about something soft like a human being?

If your immortal is really tough then the ropes might break. If the ropes are made of steel and cannot cut into the flesh of the immortal then the ropes will probably cut into the tree.

I think you will have to have an arrangement something like the picture with the car. That way several trees can grow to surround your immortal and eventually enclose them completely.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the being is forced to complete immobility, yes, the tree can grow around it.

There are photos of bikes being grown around by the trees where they were forgotten, and I have also seen metal fences or stones being inglobed from trees.

[image: tree growing around a fence]

Since the tree only grows few millimeters per year, it is key that the being is completely motionless, or, better, any movement should be less than those few millimeters per year.

If you think of the strangling fig, which grows around another tree until completely strangling it (hence the name), you see that size of the object to surround is not really an issue.

Comment: I would say "strangling" where you have "straggling", but I cannot make such a small change for you.

Answer (score 2):

This might work better if the immortal being is some kind of robot or intelligent machine and is shut off for years, decades, or centuries while the tree grows around it but is unable to crush it due to its great strength.

Eventually something might reactivate the robot and it might be strong enough to walk away, uprooting the tree.

Comment: This reminds me of Robo’s Quest from Chrono Trigger - cool thought!